# If given the limit that is a derivative, how do I find it's function and the point?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How would I solve for something like this??

$$\lim_{x\to 5} \frac{2^x - 32}{x-5}$$

using the definition of derivatives.

Comment: Short Answer: $f(x)=2^x$ and the limit is the same as $f'(5)$.

Comment: Shorter answer: by trying something, to start with.

Comment: Especially since it's [exactly the same idea as in your previous question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652655/the-given-limit-is-a-derivative-but-of-what-function-and-at-what-point)

Comment: Hint: The derivative of $f(x)$ at $a$ is $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Compare.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be instructive to show a way forward that doesn't rely on calculus.  Note we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^x-32}{x-5}&=32\frac{2^{x-5}-1}{x-5}\\\\
&=32\left(\frac{e^{\log(2)\,(x-5)}-1}{x-5}\right)
\end{align}$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using on the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{1}{1-x}\ge e^x\ge 1+x$$

for $x<1$.  Therefore, we can assert that

$$\frac{\log(2)\,(x-5)}{x-5}\le \frac{e^{\log(2)\,(x-5)}-1}{x-5}\le \frac{\frac{\log(2)\,(x-5)}{1-\log(2)\,(x-5)}}{x-5}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem gives

$$\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{2^x-32}{x-5}=32\log(2)$$

And we are done!